# How to combine Emacs primary/clipboard copy and paste behavior on MS Windows?

Tags: emacs, copy-paste

Emacs 24 changed the way copy/paste behavior works to conform with modern X applications (See [this article](http://batsov.com/articles/2011/08/19/a-peek-at-emacs24/) under "Selection changes").  They have explicitly separated primary selection and middle mouse button paste from clipboard copy/paste.

Unfortunately for me, using native (not cygwin!) Emacs 24.2.1 under MS Windows, this messes up the way I want to work.

Here is what I want:

1. Highlighting (selecting) text in Emacs automatically copies it to the Windows clipboard. If I paste it (Ctrl-V) in another Windows app it pastes. If I type C-y (yank) in Emacs, it pastes. If I middle-click in Emacs, it pastes.
2. Killing in Emacs (C-w) copies the data to the clipboard. If I paste it (Ctrl-V) in another Windows app it pastes. If I type C-y (yank) in Emacs, it pastes. If I middle-click in Emacs, it pastes **the clipboard contents, not the last selected text**.
3. Anything I copied to the clipboard from another Windows app (e.g. via Ctrl-C), can be pasted in Emacs either by typing C-y (yank) **or middle-clicking** (right now, middle clicking pastes the last selected text, not the clipboard contents).

To summarize, I think this means removing the distinction between primary selections and the clipboard in Emacs.  I want everything to act on the clipboard!

Comment: FWIW I am getting this exact behavior -- atleast #1 -- using 24.2.1 on cygwin

Comment: I'm using the native Emacs 24.2.1 (not cygwin!) described at http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/faq.html and available here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows. I'm guessing the cygwin layer takes care of the translation between primary selections (which don't exist on MS Windows) and the clipboard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following entries from NEWS seem pertinent:

- `mouse-drag-copy-region` now defaults to nil.
- mouse-2 is now bound to `mouse-yank-primary`.

This pastes from the primary selection, ignoring the kill-ring.
Previously, mouse-2 was bound to `mouse-yank-at-click`.

- To return to the previous behavior, do the following:

  - Change `select-active-regions` to nil.
  - Change `mouse-drag-copy-region` to t.
  - Change `x-select-enable-primary` to t (on X only).
  - Change `x-select-enable-clipboard` to nil.
  - Bind `mouse-yank-at-click` to mouse-2.

I think to get the previous behaviour on Windows, you need to leave both `x-select-enable-primary` and `x-select-enable-clipboard` at their current values, and maybe `select-active-regions` is not related to the change in behaviour you are complaining about here.

---

Here are the exact lines to put in your .emacs file:

```
(setq select-active-regions nil)
(setq mouse-drag-copy-region t)
(global-set-key [mouse-2] 'mouse-yank-at-click)
```

Comment: I've added the following lines to my .emacs based on what you said:
(setq select-active-regions nil)
(setq mouse-drag-copy-region t)
(global-set-key [S-mouse-2] 'mouse-yank-at-click)

This partially works. If I select text in Emacs, it copies it to the clipboard, and I can paste in another Windows app (yay!). But the middle mouse button is not working -- even after selecting something or copying something, middle mouse click gives an error at the bottom of the screen: "No selection is available".

Comment: You bound `Shift + middle mouse button`, was that intentional, or a misunderstanding? `(global-set-key [mouse-2] 'mouse-yank-at-click)` seems to work for me.

Comment: Awesome, [mouse-2] fixed it!  I'm not a Emacs lisp programmer so I had to do a Google search on how to bind mouse-2 to an action.  Guess I got the wrong info.  Now everything's working exactly how I want it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems dragging mouse does not do anything with the clipboard. The following adds that, but I don't know what it does to point and mark:

```
(defadvice mouse-drag-region (after copy-to-clipboard activate)
  (clipboard-kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (goto-char st) (push-mark nd nil t)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

- As far as I can tell, point 2 and 3 already work "out-of-the-box"?
- Also, I take it that you are not interested in having a history (like
  a kill-ring) available?
- Do you mean with highlighting "selecting it" (in emacs known as the
  region), or actually highlighting it (giving it a color, like say,
  yellow)?

If you mean selecting it, I think the problem is that Emacs would not know when your selecting ends, and thus has to copy it to clipboard? That's why you would use `Meta-W` (Alt-Shift-w) which copies it to the `kill-ring`, accessible outside of Emacs.

(I posted this here since I think the comments are confusing, but I will remove or change this answer later on)

I think you will find all the information you need in `mouse.el`:

To get there, try: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>any mouse button</kbd> and click on mouse.el to find out where it is defined. If you look for some more "`global-set-key`" within the file you might find exactly what you are looking for (I'm still not a 100% sure on this)

Comment: Yes, point 2 seems to work out of the box (thought I had trouble with that).  Point 3 does not work for middle clicking.  No, I don't care about history (kill-ring)... I've never used this feature.  Yes, I mean "selecting it" when I say highlighting.

Comment: And regarding your point "Emacs would not konw when your selecting ends", I should have pointed out that everything was fine with Emacs 23.  It did everything the way I expected.  It's only with Emacs 24 that  my expectations about "select to copy" and so on were broken.

Comment: Also, is the idea that the middle mouse button copies or pastes?

Comment: Oh I actually think it is bound to Right-mouse button perhaps?

Comment: Maybe try to double click middle-mouse, or right-mouse to see if any of those do the functionality you want?

Comment: Middle button pastes -if- I have selected something in Emacs.  However, if I have copied something to the clipboard in another Windows app, then click the middle button in Emacs, it pastes the last thing I selected in Emacs (not what I want!).  I want it to paste what is on the clipboard.

Comment: Yup I understand now. Maybe someone could find out who is stilling using the older emacs, to what middle-mouse-button is bound to.